# Dark space comic where a supercomputer rules over humans after an alien defeat

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror, space

I saw a video for this series the other day and cannot find it again, it apparently starts with a guy waking up on some space station, the only person alive there, long since abandoned.

What had apparently lead to this was way back humans found aliens and the aliens were like “hey we’re all cool so join us” and instead of that humans were like “nah we’ll just invade you” and then were defeated by the aliens alliances.

So the humans let some supercomputer rule over themselves to get back on their feet but that was bad cause now it’s turned all organic life it can get it’s keyboards on into bio-mechanical nastiness and all the aliens are terrified of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of “Humanity Lost” by [Calum Diggle](https://twitter.com/callumdiggle), as covered in [this Curious Archive video](https://youtu.be/MxVjFYi-9JU)?